# OpenGL ES - Framebuffer not drawing anything after opening Overview and going back

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

Every time I'm exiting the app, and then go back to it, the Framebuffer is not drawing anything, the screen is just black.

I was using a debugger to check if the Framebuffer object didn't miss anything and everything seemed to be fine, except this error :

**E/BpSurfaceComposerClient: Failed to transact (-1)**

When not using the framebuffer, the scene is rendering perfectly anytime.

Is there anything related to this error that makes my framebuffer not render, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

In general for Android you will lose your rendering context when the application is closed (Android doesn't want backgrounded applications holding on to a lot of memory). You usually have to recreate the rendering context when the applicatoin is reopened.